# In C++ template copy assignment operator not compatible with initializer_list?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, initializer-list

Consider I have such code:

```
#include <initializer_list>

class my_class
{
public:
    my_class() {}

    void operator = (const std::initializer_list<int>&) {} // OK
    template<typename ValueType> void operator = (const ValueType&) {} // Failed
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    my_class instance;
    instance = {1, 2};

    return 0;
}
```

The first copy assignment operator could be compiled OK with `instance = {1, 2}`. However, the template version would failed with such error:

```
code.cpp:15:14: error: no viable overloaded '='
    instance = {1, 2};
    ~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~
code.cpp:3:7: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const my_class'
class my_class
      ^
code.cpp:3:7: note: candidate function (the implicit move assignment operator) not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'my_class'
class my_class
      ^
code.cpp:9:39: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'ValueType'
    template<typename ValueType> void operator = (const ValueType&) {}
```

Why the template version is not compatible with the initializer_list?

Comment: That's probably not how you want to specify your `operator=` by the way.

Comment: Define *void operator=(const initializer_list<int> &somevariable )* such that it would follow template version for each value of int .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because initializer list is a non-deduced context. From [temp.deduct.type]:

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   — [...]
>   — A function parameter for which the associated argument is an initializer list (8.5.4) but the parameter
>   does not have a type for which deduction from an initializer list is specified (14.8.2.1). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T> void g(T);
> g({1,2,3}); // error: no argument deduced for T
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

There are some cases, however, where you can still pass in an initializer list to a template. From [temp.deduct.call]

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it `P`) with
>   the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If `P` is a dependent type,
>   removing references and *cv*-qualifiers from `P` gives `std::initializer_list<P'>` or `P'[N]` for some `P'` and
>   `N` and the argument is a non-empty initializer list (8.5.4), then deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the initializer element as
>   its argument, and in the `P'[N]` case, if `N` is a non-type template parameter, `N` is deduced from the length of the initializer list.

The examples that follow illustrate the cases in which this works:

```
template<class T> void f(std::initializer_list<T>);
f({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int

template<class T, int N> void h(T const(&)[N]);
h({1,2,3}); // T deduced to int, N deduced to 3

template<class T> void j(T const(&)[3]);
j({42}); // T deduced to int, array bound not considered
```

So in your specific case, you could do something like:

```
template <typename T>
void operator=(std::initializer_list<T> ) { }
```

Or:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void operator=(T const(&)[N]) { }
```

Although the latter apparently doesn't compile on clang, incorrectly.

Comment: The latter passes an array of type T by const reference?

Answer (score 1):

Change your template version to

```
template <typename ValueType>
void operator =(const std::initializer_list<ValueType> &) {}
```